# MultiIndex Dataframe: Sort values for each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Assume I have a `pandas` MultiIndex Dataframe similar to the one below. How do I sort the values for each group by preserving the assignment and order of the indexes? The code below works for the sorting, but I fail to resave the sorted values and `inplace` does not seem to work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([4,8,6,11,13,15], columns=['val'],
    index=[['A','A','A','B','B','B'],['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3']])

#         val
#  A  a1    4
#     a2    8
#     a3    6
#  B  b1   11
#     b2   13
#     b3   15


for idx in df.index.unique(level=0):
    tmp = df.loc[idx].sort_values(by='val')

#      val
#  a1    4
#  a3    6
#  a2    8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant of @Andrej's answer using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) rather that `apply` and [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) rather than unaligning the indices by converting to numpy:

```
df['val'] = df.groupby(level=0)['val'].transform(sorted)
```

Output:

```
      val
A a1    4
  a2    6
  a3    8
B b1   11
  b2   13
  b3   15
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you want to keep the indices as they are, just sort the "val" values:

```py
df["val"] = df.groupby(level=0)["val"].apply(pd.Series.sort_values).values
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      val
A a1    4
  a2    6
  a3    8
B b1   11
  b2   13
  b3   15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create another dataframe:

```
data =  df.reset_index(names='group', level=0).sort_values(['group', 'val'].values
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print(df1)

# Output
      val
A a1    4
  a2    6
  a3    8
B b1   11
  b2   13
  b3   15
```